# Android JNI GetMethodID fails to find a method in release build

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am calling a java method from C++ in android app. Works fine in debug but GetMethodID fails in release build.

```
// Java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        showKeyboard();
    }
    public void showKeyboard()
    {
        Log.i("my_app", "MainActivity::showKeyboard");
        //...
    }
}

// C++
JavaVM* gJvm; // Saved in JNI_OnLoad()
jobject gMainActivity; // Saved in call Java -> C++
                       // using JNIEnv->NewGlobalRef(mainActivity)
void my_thread_func() {
    JNIEnv* jniEnv = nullptr;
    gJvm->AttachCurrentThread(&jniEnv, nullptr);;
    jclass activityClass = jniEnv->GetObjectClass(gMainActivity);
    jmethodID methodId = jniEnv->GetMethodID(activityClass, "showKeyboard", "()V");
    // Debug build: methodId is valid
    // Release build: methodId is null
}
```

showKeyboard is called from onCreate only for debug purposes. I can see the line "MainActivity::showKeyboard" in the output. Also it works as expected in debug build.

I suspect java optimization kicks in and removes the method in release. Although it's called in onCreate, it may just get inlined. I tried to add 50+ lines of log prints hoping to discourage inlining but it didn't change anything.

Is there a way to disable java optimization for this method? Or how else can I troubleshoot it?

Comment: "I suspect java optimization kicks in and removes the method in release" -- another possibility is that you have turned on obfuscation, and the method is being renamed. You may need to adjust your ProGuard/R8 rules to `--keep` this method so it does not get renamed.

Comment: Alternatively, use the [@Keep annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, compiling code in release mode turns on Proguard minification and obfuscation. If you look at the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code#keep-code), you will find several options:

1. Use the [@Keep annotation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/annotation/Keep) on the `showKeyboard` method. This will get picked up by the default proguard ruleset and prevent the method from being renamed or removed.
2. Write your own Proguard rules to keep the method. I think this ought to look like:

```
-keep public class com.example.MainActivity {
    public void showKeyboard();
}
```

Comment: Yes, adding @Keep before the method worked for me.